# ITextSharp add number to file name if it exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, desktop-application

Dumb question but doing a method that creates a PDF for a receipt with `ITextSharp` and the name for the file is based in the client name and the date of the purchase
but if I have 2 purchases in the same day `ITextSharp` just overwrites the file. I want it so it adds a (1), (2), etc to the end of the file name

```
string aux1 = data.getString("select full_name from clients where id=" + cboClient.SelectedValue);

string aux2 = getWrittenDate(DateTime.Today);

SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

sfd.FileName = "receipt" + aux1 + aux2 + ".pdf";    

Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream((sfd.FileName), FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the file already exists using `File.Exists(filePath)` and rename it manually in that case.

A good solution would be to add the time of purchase to file name to make it unique.

Hope this helps :)